# PolideaHow can set Notify value to True on a specific Characteristic and Polidea/RXBluethootKit with IOS

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

Hi I'm trying to write some Data to a device via BLE, I'm using RXBluethootKit for Swift but I have difficult to set Notify "on" in a specific characteristic before write a value.

this is my code:

```
func connect(for state: BluetoothState)  -> Observable<Characteristic>   {
        return manager.observeState()
            .startWith(state)
            .filter { $0 == .poweredOn }
            .flatMap { _ in self.manager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [self.PERDIX_UUID]) }
            .take(1)
            .flatMap { $0.peripheral.establishConnection()
            .flatMap { $0.discoverServices([self.PERDIX_UUID]) }.asObservable()
            .flatMap { Observable.from($0) }
            .flatMap { $0.discoverCharacteristics([self.PERDIX_CHAR_UUID])}.asObservable()
            .flatMap { Observable.from($0) }
    }


connect(for: state)
            .subscribe(onNext: { characteristic in
                print("Discovered characteristic: \(characteristic.characteristic.uuid)")
                self.result.text = characteristic.characteristic.uuid.uuidString
                characteristic.writeValue(data as Data, type: .withResponse)
                    .subscribe { event in
                        //respond to errors / successful read
                }

        })
```

Any suggestion?
thanks

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I can't able to set notification on using RXBluethootkit I didn't found any way. I'd like to do something like : peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)